# add a hyperlinked url in infowindow. attribute url from xml file of coordinates - Google Maps Platform

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to import a url attribute from a linked xml file of map locations and display a hyperlink in the Infowindow.

Infowindow currently only displays link with no hyperlink, I need a piece of code that will add the hyperlink using the url from the xml file and surrounding the result with PROFILE

right now I'm running into trouble because of the quotes.

Map: https://worldteleport.site-ym.com/mpage/Map_NEW2

Code:

```
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
<title>World Teleport Map 2.0</title>
<style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
    * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
    height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
<script>
      var customLabel = {
       Teleport: {
          label: 'T'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {

var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
           [ { "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#f5f5f5" } ] }, { "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#616161" } ] }, { "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#f5f5f5" } ] }, { "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#bdbdbd" } ] }, { "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#eeeeee" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.text", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#757575" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#e5e5e5" } ] }, { "featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#9e9e9e" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#ffffff" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.arterial", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#757575" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#dadada" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#616161" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.local", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "road.local", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#9e9e9e" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.line", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#e5e5e5" } ] }, { "featureType": "transit.station", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#eeeeee" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [ { "color": "#c9c9c9" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#82d1fd" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] }, { "featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#9e9e9e" } ] } ],
         {name: 'Styled Map'});

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.273056, -11.346264),
          zoom: 3,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
                    'styled_map']
          }
        });

        map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
        map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('https://worldteleport.site-ym.com/resource/resmgr/scripts/Teleport_PINS.xml', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var tier = markerElem.getAttribute('tier');
              var site = markerElem.getAttribute('site');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = tier
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = site
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);

              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var image = 'https://www.worldteleport.org/resource/resmgr/scripts/pin_member.png';
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: image,
                label: icon.image
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });

    xmlUrl = "https://worldteleport.site-ym.com/resource/resmgr/scripts/Markers.xml";

    loadMarkers();

        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

function loadMarkers() {
    map.markers = map.markers || []
    downloadUrl(xmlUrl, function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var tier = markers[i].getAttribute("tier");
            var site = markers[i].getAttribute("site");
            var marker_image = markers[i].getAttribute('markerimage');
            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address1")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("address2")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("address3")+"<br />"+markers[i].getAttribute("postcode");
            var image = {
              url: marker_image,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 132),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(71, 132)
            };
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<div class='infowindow'><b>" + name + "</b><br/>" + tier + "<br/>"+ site +"<br/></div>";
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: point,
              icon: image, 
              title: name
            });
            map.markers.push(marker);
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
    });
}

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQGTqENdfELfxLInlrbi2c78yP7d8sKc4&amp;callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: What does your XML look like? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Your "live" page has javascript errors: `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: bindInfoWindow is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Using one of the two loops that are creating markers with infowindows in you code, I don't see any issues with quotes:

Adding the code below adds the hyperlink to the URL text:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = site;
var text = document.createElement('text');
text.textContent = site
infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
a.appendChild(text);
infowincontent.appendChild(a);
```

full marker processing loop:

```
var markers = xml.getElementsByTagName('marker');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
  var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
  var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
  var tier = markerElem.getAttribute('tier');
  var site = markerElem.getAttribute('site');
  var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
  var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

  var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
  var strong = document.createElement('strong');
  strong.textContent = name
  infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
  infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

  var text = document.createElement('text');
  text.textContent = tier
  infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  infowincontent.appendChild(text);

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = site;
  var text = document.createElement('text');
  text.textContent = site
  infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  a.appendChild(text);
  infowincontent.appendChild(a);

  var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tazmjk2n/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var customLabel = {
  Teleport: {
    label: 'T'
  },
  bar: {
    label: 'B'
  }
};
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.273056, -11.346264),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
        'styled_map'
      ]
    }
  });

  map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // loading xml string and parsing it, since can't easily load XML asynchronously on jsfiddle/code snippet
  var xml = parseXml(xmlStr);
  var markers = xml.getElementsByTagName('marker');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
    var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
    var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
    var tier = markerElem.getAttribute('tier');
    var site = markerElem.getAttribute('site');
    var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
    var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
      parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
    var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
    var strong = document.createElement('strong');
    strong.textContent = name
    infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

    var text = document.createElement('text');
    text.textContent = tier
    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    infowincontent.appendChild(text);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = site;
    var text = document.createElement('text');
    text.textContent = site
    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    a.appendChild(text);
    infowincontent.appendChild(a);

    var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    if (id == 1)
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}

var xmlStr = '<markers><marker id="1" name="Eutelsat Rambouillet Teleport" tier="Certified - Tier 4" site="http://www.worldteleport.org/members/?id=38992582" lat="48.549400" lng="1.782600" type="Certified Teleport"/><marker id="2" name="Arqiva Chalfont Grove Teleport (London) UK" tier="Certified - Tier 4" site="" lat="51.615214" lng="-0.576008" type="Certified Teleport"/><marker id="3" name="Batelco - Ras Abu Jarjur (RJR)" tier="Certified - Provisonal" site="" lat="51.615214" lng="26.0716346" type="Certified Teleport"/><marker id="4" name="Elara Comunicaciones" tier="Certified - Provisonal" site="" lat="19.296691" lng="-99.155804" type="Certified Teleport"/></markers>';

var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
  [{
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#f5f5f5"
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#616161"
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#f5f5f5"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#bdbdbd"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#eeeeee"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#757575"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#e5e5e5"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#9e9e9e"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#ffffff"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#757575"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#dadada"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#616161"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#9e9e9e"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#e5e5e5"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#eeeeee"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#c9c9c9"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#82d1fd"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#9e9e9e"
    }]
  }], {
    name: 'Styled Map'
  });
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! very helpful, now I just need a script to choose a custom icon image using an attribute from the xml file.

Comment: That is a different question.

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)